# React does not refresh after an update on the state (an array of objects)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm displaying `cards` with a map function on my state.
The state looks like this:

```
[{ position: "0", state: "pending" }, 
{ position: "1", state: "pending" }, 
{ position: "2", state: "pending" }]
```

In a function, I'm changing the "state" from "pending" to "right", but it does not refresh anything on the page.

```
export const Card: React.FC<ICardOwnProps> = ({ }) => {
    const [rollingCards, setRollingCards] = useState<IRollingCard[]>([{ position: "0", state: "pending" }, { position: "1", state: "pending" }, { position: "2", state: "pending" }])

    const handleClick = () => {
        let newArray = rollingCards;
        newArray.splice(0, 1)
        setRollingCards(newArray);
    }

    useEffect(() => { console.log("check changes") })

    return (
        <StyledCard className="Card">
            {rollingCards.map((v, i, a) =>
                <Container key={i} className={"position" + v.position} >{v.state}</Container>
            )}
            <div className="card__container--button">
                <button onClick={handleClick}>Oui</button>
                <button>Non</button>
                {rollingCards[0].state}
           </div>
        </StyledCard>
    );
}
```

From now, nothings changes, but when I add a new state piece that I update at the same time as the rollingCards, it'll update. I added a counter, and with that, it updates the page.

(I also tried to splice the array to see if React would update, it did not)

Any idea why I've got this weird behavior ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is because React does a referential equality comparison of props/state when making a decision to rerender.

newArray has the same reference as rollingCards due to which the functional component does not re render on setRollingCards

Change

```
setRollingCards(newArray)
```

to

```
setRollingCards([...newArray])
```

This creates a new array (new reference) with the elements from newArray

Working solution:
https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-wave-9kgqq

Comment: This is very very informative. So referencial equality is just comparison and is not a deep comparison right. Just checks array and not elements change within objects which requires deep comparison right?

Answer (score 1):

Because react uses `Object.is` to determine if the state has changed.

In your code, `newArray` is the same reference as `rollingCards`, you can use `Object.is(newArray, rollingCards)` to check.

```js
const handleClick = () => {
    let newArray = rollingCards;
    newArray.splice(0, 1)   // Object.is(newArray, rollingCards) is true
    setRollingCards(newArray);
}
```

So you can change it like this.

```
setRollingCards(rollingCards.filter((item, index) => index !== 0);
```

> Not only this method, as long as it is a different reference